# how to get relationship data in adonis js

Tags: javascript, typescript, relational-database, adonis.js, lucid

I have a relational model in adonis that I want to retrieve the data (Post belongs to Category). I've set up the relationship in both of migration and model,

But when I try to get the category name from the first Post with

```
const posts = await Post.first()
return posts?.category.name
```

it returns "cannot read data" even though I've seeded the database with the correct data

Answer (score 1):

in Model we  need to define a releation

```
class Post extends Model {

category() {
        return this.belongsTo('App/Models/Category', 'category_id').select('id', 'name');
}
}
```

Following code is used to get data of relation

```
 let post = await Post.query().with('category').first()
```